# Looping throught an array and setting a flag based in a previous loop condition

Tags: arrays

I have the following array:

```
array:37 [▼
  "09:00" => Appointment {rows = 4}
  "09:15" => ""
  "09:30" => ""
  "09:45" => ""
  "10:00" => ""
  "10:15" => ""
  "10:30" => ""
  "10:45" => ""
  "11:00" => ""
  "11:15" => ""
  "11:30" => ""
  "11:45" => ""
  "12:00" => Appointment { rows => 2}
  "12:15" => ""
  "12:30" => ""
  "12:45" => ""
]
```

Inside $appointment there is the attribute appointment->duration which is an integer data type

I want  to loop through the array take the value of "duration" and make a set a flag in the folloing empty arrays position. Example:

```
array:37 [▼
  "09:00" => Appointment {rows = 4}
  "09:15" => "yes"
  "09:30" => "yes"
  "09:45" => "yes"  //this is the fourth 
  "10:00" => ""
  "10:15" => ""
  "10:30" => ""
  "10:45" => ""
  "11:00" => ""
  "11:15" => ""
  "11:30" => ""
  "11:45" => ""
  "12:00" => Appointment { duration => 2}
  "12:15" => "yes" //this is the second
  "12:30" => ""
  "12:45" => ""
]
```

I did this:

```
$loops = 0;
$calendar = $calendar[0];
foreach ($calendar as $key => $appointment) {
    if ($appointment) {
        $loops = $appointment->rows;
    } else {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $loops; $i++) {
            $calendar[$key] = 'ja';
        }
        $i = 0; $loops = 0;
    }

}
```

but I just get one flag instead the desired numbers (duration).

```
array:37 [▼
  "09:00" => Appointment {#6930 ▶}
  "09:15" => "ja"
  "09:30" => ""
  "09:45" => ""
  "10:00" => ""
....
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't understand how $appointment has a (rows) properity. Also, the second appointment duration looks like a condition not an integer.

Comment: It have one. I Edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<?php
//BUILD ARRAY
$calendar = [
  "09:00" => [],
  "09:15" => "",
  "09:30" => "",
  "09:45" => "",
  "10:00" => "",
  "10:15" => "",
  "10:30" => "",
  "10:45" => "",
  "11:00" => "",
  "11:15" => "",
  "11:30" => "",
  "11:45" => "",
  "12:00" => [],
  "12:15" => "",
  "12:30" => "",
  "12:45" => ""
];

$calendar["09:00"]["Appointment"]["rows"] = 4;
$calendar["12:00"]["Appointment"]["rows"] = 2;
//END BUILD ARRAy

$loops = 0;
$appointment_index = -1;

foreach ($calendar as $key => $appointment) {
    $current_index = array_search($key,array_keys($calendar)); // Get current index of $calendar array
    if ($appointment) {
        $appointment_index = $current_index; // Store appointment index
        $loops = $appointment["Appointment"]["rows"]; // Get loops
    } 

    if($current_index - $appointment_index < $loops ){ // Find the next N elemnts after $appointment->rows 
       if($current_index != $appointment_index) // Skip appointment element
       {
           $calendar[$key] = "Ja";
       }
    }
}
print_r ($calendar);

?>
```

Comment: I went this solution through and there is an small correction inthis line: $loops = $appointment["Appointment"]["rows"];. It should be $loops = $appointment['rows']; and then works perfectly!. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I just checked your input and expected output. Almost you have done, but you need little change with else part.

Here you should have 'else if' rather than only 'else'. See

```
else if($loops > 0) {
    $calendar[$key] = "Yes";
    $loops--;
}
```

Here is full code to get your expected output.

```
$calendar =  array(
    "09:00" => array('rows' => 4),
    "09:15" => "",
    "09:30" => "",
    "09:45" => "",
    "10:00" => "",
    "10:15" => "",
    "10:30" => "",
    "10:45" => "",
    "11:00" => "",
    "11:15" => "",
    "11:30" => "",
    "11:45" => "",
    "12:00" => array('rows' => 2),
    "12:15" => "",
    "12:30" => "",
    "12:45" => "",
);

$loops = 0;
foreach($calendar as $key => $appointment) {
    if(is_array($appointment)) {
        $loops = $appointment['rows'] - 1;
    } else if($loops > 0) {
        $calendar[$key] = "Yes";
        $loops--;
    }
}
print_r($calendar);
```